# Convert image stored in MSSQL blob to image file?

Tags: php, sql-server, blob

I have the following data (`jpg` image) stored in MSSQL BLOB. How can I convert it to image ready for display?

> 0xffd8ffe000104a46494600010101006000600000ffdb004300080606070605080707070909080a0c140d0c0b0b0c1912130f141d1a1f1e1d1a1c1c20242e2720222c231c1c2837292c30313434341f27393d38323c2e333432ffdb0043010909090c0b0c180d0d1832211c213232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232ffc000110800b200b203012200021101031101ffc4001f0000010501010101010100000000000000000102030405060708090a0bffc400b5100002010303020403050504040000017d01020300041105122131410613516107227114328191a108

I know that if BLOB contains the binary data of an image, writing it directly to file should do the trick, but it's not working.

```
$blob_data = ''; // the string above

file_put_contents( 'test_image.jpg', $blob_data ); // output is broken image
```

Comment: It would be better if you can show some code, so that others can figure out what has gone wrong.

Comment: It may be a binary image, but is it a jpg image.  You need to know the original format before it can be converted to jpg and displayed as such.

Comment: @DanGuzman, yes, I get that data from a table, there are column for image extension and image mime type as well. Mime type is: `image/jpeg` and extension is `.jpg`

Comment: Is the data value example you posted truncated to 512 characters?  It doesn't seem be a valid jpg value.  No conversion should be needed if it's already a binary jpg image.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I didn't notice that... I checked it and it seems that the data is stored in `tinyint`, so probably there's something wrong with the data itself. Can you convert your comment to answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in your question doesn't seem be a valid jpg value. No conversion should be needed if it's already a valid binary jpg image stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Have just had the same need to convert blob into image.

You need to remove the starting `0x` and then convert it with `hex2bin()`.

```
<?php
  $source = substr($blob, 2);
  $image = hex2bin($source);
  file_put_contents('image.jpg', $image);
?>
```